# socket library exits for web but not for cli

Tags: php, sockets, wamp, command-line-interface

I have got an strange problem recently....I run wamp in windows 7...I wanted to use sockets so I have enabled sockets extension and checked in the browser if they have been enabled.

```
   if (!function_exists('socket_create')) {
        echo 'Unable to load the socket library. Please enable it under your php.ini file.';
        exit();
    }
    else{
        echo 'exist';
    }
```

This goes into else if executed in browser...but same goes into if executed through command line prompt. I just don't understand how's this possible. please help me if anyone else got the same problem.

Comment: Have you restarted server?

Comment: yes I did restrart my server. That's why I got it running in browser

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I GOT IT...It's coz wamp is using different files for apache execution and CLI